# JToolBar always float

Tags: java, swing, uimanager, jtoolbar

When you add a JToolBar to a component, you can drag it out and it create a new floating window while the parent component is also there. How can I make JToolBar show this floating window automatically with the parent invisible?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. A toolbar generally has components that perform actions pertaining to whatever is inside the parent frame, so disposing of the frame while keeping the toolbar visible seems a bit silly. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: No, you've understood it correctly. There is another window which is what the components on the toolbar act upon, but I am not allowed to add components to it. This is why I want the self-floating toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicToolBarUI
and set its parent to the instance of a container (JDialog, JFrame). This should create a floating toolbar by default.

You can set the BasicToolbarUI like below:

```
ui = new BasicToolBarUI();
toolBar = new JToolBar();
toolBar.setUI(ui);
```